# Increase download speed for encrypted openssl

Tags: c++, openssl

Hey I've been using openssl as a secure communication method between a client and my server, I've been downloading updates to the client using encrypted ssl and the speed is insanely slow, the packed file is around 6~ mb and takes 2-3 minutes to download. is there anyway to speed up openssl without taking a massive security hit? thanks!

Comment: Your question lacks a [mre].  [Edit] the question to include the code that shows us how the data goes from unencrypted, thru the encryption, and is sent across the network.

Comment: Also, have you tested the download speed without encryption?